# react - material-ui appbar icon touch event doesn't fire

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I click on the element AppBar, icon on the left, _handleClick()  method should execute.
I can't get console message.
I'm using material-ui framework and the attribute onLeftIconButtonTouchTap is provided for a callback function for when the left icon is selected via a touch tap.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppBar, IconButton } from 'material-ui'
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';

let injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");

//Needed for onTouchTap
//Can go away when react 1.0 release
//Check this repo:
//https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin
injectTapEventPlugin();


class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  _handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Show/Hide the LeftMenu
    window.console.log("Click!");
  }

  render() {
       return (
        <AppBar title="Arasaaccc"
                iconElementLeft={ <IconButton>
                                    <MoreVertIcon/>
                                  </IconButton> }
                onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={ this._handleClick }
                isInitiallyOpen={ true } />


      )
  }
}

export default Header
```

However it works with another component:

```
class Prueba extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  _handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.console.log("Click!");
  }
  render (){
    return (
      <h1 onClick={this._handleClick}>Prueba Prueba Prueba</h1>
      )
  }
}
export default Prueba;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you specify an icon for the AppBar component, onLeftIconButtonTouchTap event does not work.
Either you don't specify an icon:

```
<AppBar title="Arasaaccc" 
         onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={ this._handleClick }
                            isInitiallyOpen={ true } />
```

Or you apply the event on the IconButton component:

```
<AppBar title="Arasaaccc"
        iconElementLeft={ <IconButton onTouchTap={ this._handleClick }  >
                            <MoreVertIcon />
                          </IconButton> }
        isInitiallyOpen={ true } />
```

**Edit:** Note that, according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2482), the problem should be solved. You still can't have a a `_handleClick` on both of `iconElementLeft` and `onLeftIconButtonTouchTap`, either one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problems with your code, so my guess is you'll need the [React-Tap-Event-Plugin](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui#react-tap-event-plugin). The docs say this dependency is temporary and will go away once react v1.0 is released.

Comment: I guess React-Tap-Event-Plugin is not the reason (just for waiting 300ms). Anyway, I updated the code and I did something similar with a simple Class

Comment: Does it work with the plugin? Your other component uses an onClick event, so of course, that will fire natively.

Comment: Nope, the plugin doesn't help :-(

Comment: Wondering if this would do the trick? https://github.com/hartmamt/react-with-tap-events/blob/master/src/react-patch.js

Comment: Dig deeper [here](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin/issues/22). Some tweaks may be necessary with certain versions of React and React-Tap-Event-Plugin so that you get to use the tap events.

Comment: I think plugin is ok. It's something related to material-ui: I can execute onTittleTouchTap event, from AppBar. However onLeftIconButtonTouchTap  event is not being fired